# Помогите решить проблему со scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms

Программа - своего рода некий чат.Программа считывает файл с сервера с некоторой частотой. С каждым новым считыванием scrollbar прокручивается к началу textbox'a, из-за чего нормально читать чат не получается.Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы scrollbar оставался неподвижным?

Comment: а если новые вверх?

Comment: Мы же на голове ходим

Comment: мне в почтовом онлайн-клиенте новые письма вверх добавляются, смс в моём телефоне также отсортированы по убыванию даты получения. Впрочем не настаиваю))

Comment: Вспомните ВК, да и любой другой проект, где есть чат, это же не удобно, когда сообщения идут вверх.

Comment: совсем неподвижным его сделать не получится, но можно возвращать в исходную позицию после обновления текста. Естественно положение курсора нужно предварительно запомнить.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898307/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-multiline-text-box